# Nexus to proxy a repository from a different nexus instance

Tags: nexus

My main question is whether it is possible in Nexus OSS to proxy a repository which is a hosted repository in a separate nexus instance. I.e.

nexus instance 1: `http://instance-one:8081/nexus`
nexus instance 2: `http://instance-two:8081/nexus`

I want to add the releases of instance 2 (`http://instance-two:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases`) as a proxy repository in instance-one.

When I try to do this, the repository in instance-one says 'In Service - Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable'.

Is it true that this type of proxying is only available in nexus pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is of course easily possible in Nexus Open Source. You must have some sort of configuration issue. For starters confirm that you can ping instance 2 from instance 1. Then ensure that the urls you have configured in the proxy repo are reachable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you say the URLs are reachable, do you mean trying to access them from a browser?

Comment: Solved! The other nexus system was one the same server and therefore it should not go through the general proxy settings set on the Server Administration page